# Creating Tab in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a tab in HTML that consists of 4 tabs in a verticle column as shown in the following [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/DDV98/54/) :

http://jsfiddle.net/DDV98/54/

HTML sample

```
<div id="pensyarah-tab">
<div id="column">
<div class="subnav">
<ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab0">Biodata</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Academic</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Experiment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Expertise</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tabcontainer">
          <!-- Tab0 -->
        <div id="tab0" class="tab active clear">
        <table class="no-border fl_left">
        <tr>
          <td>Nama</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>This is name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Akademik</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>PhD ( -- ), BSc ( -- )</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jawatan</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>Director</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bidang Kajian</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>Applied Statistics</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Emel</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>hey@me.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ext</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>09 - 699 3154</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bilik</td>
          <td>:</td>
          <td>D2-2-23</td>
        </tr>

      </table>    
      </div>         
      <!-- Tab0 -->

    <!-- Tab1 -->
      <div id="tab1" class="tab clear">
        <h1>Dr Antimage</h1>

        <div id="content-pensyarah"> 

            <table class="no-border fl_left">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Kelayakan Akademik</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>BSc ( Industrial Mathematics ) -- </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>PhD ( Mathematics ) --</td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>           
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Tab1 -->

      <!-- Tab2 -->
          <div id="tab2" class="tab clear">
        <h1>Dr Ancient Appiration</h1>

        <div id="content-pensyarah"> 

            <table class="no-border fl_left">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Kelayakan Akademik</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>BSc ( Industrial Mathematics )-- </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>PhD ( Mathematics ) ---</td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>           
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Tab2 -->

    <!-- Tab3 -->
          <div id="tab3" class="tab clear">
        <h1>Dr GG</h1>

        <div id="content-pensyarah"> 

            <table class="no-border fl_left">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Kelayakan Akademik</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>BSc ( Industrial Mathematics ) -0 </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>PhD ( Mathematics ) 0-</td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>           
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Tab3 -->
</div></div>
```

The problem is that I am unable to load the default tab (tab0 which has the class active) when the result page loads.

Please take note that I have deleted the Column part and Column Navigation Part in my CSS file, so I think that the problem may either exists in my Tabs part at the most bottom of my CSS file or it exists within my HTML file.

I greatly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#pensyarah-tab .tab-links a').on('click', function (e) {
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        $('#pensyarah-tab ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

        // Change/remove current tab to active
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#pensyarah-tab .tab-links .active a').click();
});
```

### **Demo**

Comment: I did the same solution and then saw yours. Nice job.

Answer (score 1):

you have :

```
.tabcontainer .tab .active {
            display:block;
        }
```

change it to :

```
.tabcontainer .active {
            display:block;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/DDV98/56/)**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#pensyarah-tab .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        $('#pensyarah-tab ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

        // Change/remove current tab to active
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.tab-links a:first').click();
});
```

You need to set the tab as active on DOM ready. The above example works.

With `a:first`, it selects first anchor tag, and your click function handles the rest.

Or

Add this in your CSS.

```
.tabcontainer .active {
    display:block;
}
```

Not

```
.tabcontainer .tabs .active {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: you know that `$('a:first')` will trigger on first `a` element .. and not necessarily on that tabs ... maybe `$('#pensyarah-tab .tab-links a:first')`

Comment: @ shaunakde Ok i get it thanks for the help.

@ Mihailorga Yea my code is actually a lot more longer, so i use id to separate them.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have `display: none;` in `.tabcontainer .tab`, so every tab container is originally hidden.

You may do one of the following:

- Show one within the `$(document).ready`,
- Add `display: block;` to `.active` class and use the `active` class inside your JavaScript code, instead of showing and hiding the elements,
- Or [simulate a click on the first tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23902971/240613).

Comment: Yea i did add the "active" class so that it's set to `display: block` in the `.tabcontainer .tab .active`