# How create a program with three screens separate in Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a program with three screens separate and different cadastre using Apps Scripts. For example:

Menu bar:

> Cadastre Screen 1
>   Cadastre Screen 2
>   Cadastre Screen 3

When you click the menu Cadastre Screen 2, this screen should be loaded blank. When you click the menu Cadastre Screen 1, this screen should be loaded blank.

Read this article in Google https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices (Separate HTML, CSS, and JavaScript). However, I wonder if there is another way to do this.

Please help me?

Thank you.

Sincerely,
Thiago.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want a single page application with some kind of navigation system.  You can achieve that with Apps Script HTML Service, but it's not really an Apps Script issue.  It's HTML and JavaScript.  There are various ways you could achieve this.

- Load all the HTML all at once, then show and hide elements.
- Retrieve HTML from the server, and change the HTML in an element
- Some combination of the above two.

Content can be shown or hidden with JavaScript and the DOM.

```
document.getElementById("idPageOne").style.display = none;
document.getElementById("idPageTwo").style.display = inline;
```

The above code will hide an HTML element with an id of "idPageOne" and show an HTML element with an id of "idPageTwo".

You can look at posts like this one:

[stackoverflow creating-tabs-in-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902925/creating-tab-in-html)

Comment: Hello Sandy.

Thank you for your help. This seems the right thing to do. Also I liked the example link he shared.